# ReactJS - Pass parameter from blade to JSX

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs, laravel-blade

I'm using and **React** and **Laravel**.

I'm able to pass values from my controller to the blade view. But how can I pass this value from the view to the **JSX**.

My view looks like this:

```
<?php
    echo $max_price;
?>

@extends('layouts.master')


@section('content')
    <div id="stocks"></div>
@endsection
```

I can access max_price here. But how can I pass it to the JSX file.

The JSX file which renders the pageComponent

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var PageComponent  = require('./PageComponent');

if (document.getElementById('stocks')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<PageComponent  />,document.getElementById('stocks'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window` object to share data from blade to js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.maxPrice= {!! json_encode($max_price) !!};
</script>
```

and then you can use `window.maxPrice` in your `jsx` files:

```
ReactDOM.render(<PageComponent maxPrice={window.maxPrice} />, 
  document.getElementById('stocks'));
```

However, I would not recommend to access window variable from jsx directly. Instead, you could wrap accessing `window` into some helper method:

```
export function getMaxPrice() {
  return window.maxPrice;
}
```

and then in jsx:

```
ReactDOM.render(<PageComponent maxPrice={getMaxPrice()} />, 
  document.getElementById('stocks'));
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. Is there a better or more preferred way of doing this, instead of passing the variables in the window? 

In a previous project I had used something like this: in the controller put, return view('stocks')->with('MAX_PRICE', "900"); 

And in the js component I was directly able to use MAX_PRICE. But it doesn't work here.

Comment: you can use localStorage I thing rather than window object. saving non critical values to the localStorage and reading from it can also work both ways.